# How to modify a table to have the right agregate with SQL

Tags: sql, dataset, spotfire

I am trying to work on a vizualisation on a dataset which is a bit tricky.

My excel file looks like:

```
col1        col2      col3   Production 2017   Production 2018
engine 1    4CV       1.8L      650 Units         800 units
engine 1    6CV       1.9L      700 units         300 units
Engine 2    4CV       1.8L      450 units         450 units
```

I am working with Spotfire as vizualisation tool if i want to work on the year as Aggregate i would need:

```
col1        col2      col3   Production    Year
engine 1    4CV       1.8L       650       2017 
engine 1    4CV       1.8L       800       2018 
engine 1    6CV       1.9L       700       2017
engine 1    6CV       1.9L       300       2018
Engine 2    4CV       1.8L       450       2017
Engine 2    4CV       1.8L       450       2018
```

Do you guys know how to convert my first table to the second one maybe with a SQL QUERY

Answer (score 2):

What you want is an `UNPIVOT`. I'm not sure how you would utilize SQL queries when connected to an embedded data source, as excel. If this was stored in a RDBMS then perhaps. Either way, you want an `UNPIVOT` in SQL or in Spotfire.

- Insert > Transformation
- Under Transformations select Unpivot and click Add
- Select col1, col2, and col3 and add them to the "Columns to pass through"
- Select Production 2017, Production 2018 and any other column years you have and add them to "Columns to transform"
- Click OK

That will leave your data looking like this:

```
+----------+------+------+-----------------+-----------+
|   col1   | col2 | col3 |    Category     |   Value   |
+----------+------+------+-----------------+-----------+
| engine 1 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2017 | 650 Units |
| engine 1 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2018 | 800 units |
| engine 1 | 6CV  | 1.9L | Production 2017 | 700 units |
| engine 1 | 6CV  | 1.9L | Production 2018 | 300 units |
| Engine 2 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2017 | 450 units |
| Engine 2 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2018 | 450 units |
+----------+------+------+-----------------+-----------+
```

- Click Edit > Column Properties
- Change the name of the Category Column and Value Column to Production and Year

Now your data will look like this

```
+----------+------+------+-----------------+------------+
|   col1   | col2 | col3 |      Year       | Production |
+----------+------+------+-----------------+------------+
| engine 1 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2017 | 650 Units  |
| engine 1 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2018 | 800 units  |
| engine 1 | 6CV  | 1.9L | Production 2017 | 700 units  |
| engine 1 | 6CV  | 1.9L | Production 2018 | 300 units  |
| Engine 2 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2017 | 450 units  |
| Engine 2 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2018 | 450 units  |
+----------+------+------+-----------------+------------+
```

If you want the year by itself, then

- Insert > Calculated Column
- Insert this expression `Right([Year],4)`

Your data will now look like this

```
+----------+------+------+-----------------+------------+---------+
|   col1   | col2 | col3 |      Year       | Production | TheYear |
+----------+------+------+-----------------+------------+---------+
| engine 1 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2017 | 650 Units  |    2017 |
| engine 1 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2018 | 800 units  |    2018 |
| engine 1 | 6CV  | 1.9L | Production 2017 | 700 units  |    2017 |
| engine 1 | 6CV  | 1.9L | Production 2018 | 300 units  |    2018 |
| Engine 2 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2017 | 450 units  |    2017 |
| Engine 2 | 4CV  | 1.8L | Production 2018 | 450 units  |    2018 |
+----------+------+------+-----------------+------------+---------+
```

**Note, you can do this when you "add data" to your dxp. Anytime the data is refreshed, these transformations will take place**

Comment: Great answer thank you very much i am trying this this afternoon! Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem @oilid.b !

Comment: It's working perfectly such a great tip! Thanks again for the detailed explanations

Comment: No worries at all @oilid.b

Comment: Hi, i was wondering if there is a way of keeping the 2 versions of the dataset. That way i'll keep in a view my first Data set and everytime i'll update it it will transform it in another view with the transformation needed.

Comment: When you refresh the data the transformation will run again so you won't have to do thus each time

Comment: I wasn't clear @scsimon sorry. I am wondering if instead of transform my data ( called 'table1') i could duplicate my data as a new table then transform it ( keep 'table1' as it is, duplicate it as 'table2' then unpivot on 'table2'.

Answer (score 1):

Just use two queries, projecting therein only one of the two years in each query and then UNION both queries together. Something like this:

```
SELECT  col1, col2, col3, Prod2017 FROM [YourTable]
UNION ALL
SELECT  col1, col2, col3, Prod2018 FROM [YourTable]
```

Rest of the things are simple formatting issues and can be achieved using `CONVERT`.

Comment: Thanks it,s a way of doing it for sure.

Comment: If someone has a solution to change the table straight i would love to.